# TLS (Transport Layer Security) Issue when Creating Channel in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, tls1.3

I'm developing a project with Hyperledger Fabric using the test-network, and while trying to run the components separately, I encountered two issues when calling the createChannel script.

Firstly, when I executed the script separately using:

```
./scripts/createChannel.sh "mychannel" 3 5 true 0
```

I encountered the following problem:

**configtxgen tool not found.**

However, when I ran it from within the script directly using:

```
./network.sh createChannel -c channel5
```

I received the image error.
Could you please help me understand why the configtxgen tool is not found when executing the script separately, and what might be causing the error when calling the method to create the channel directly within the script?